# Laravel : Accessing attributes of an Eloquent object results in 'Trying to get property of non-object' error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Controller function I am calling the following code:

`$ad = Ad::activeRegular()->with('category', 'city')->limit($limit_regular_ads)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`

and it successfully returns an `Ad` Eloquent model object.  This object has a relation defined in `Ad.php` as follows:

```
class Ad extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**Now the problem**

But in my view when I try to fetch the `Category` of this `Ad`(vertisement) with the following code:

```
foreach($ad as $rad){
 var_dump($rad->category->category_name)
}
```

it fires

> Trying to get property of non-object

For information, `var_dump($rad->category)` successfully prints the contents of the related `Category` object.

Why can't I access the attributes of the object this way. 
even `$rad->category()->category_name` throws the same error.

Comment: Can you print the var_dump($rad->category) results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because one of the ads doesn't have a category.

You can use [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional) helper you if want to show name only if ad has a category:

```
foreach ($ad as $rad) {
    var_dump(optional($rad->category)->category_name)
}
```

Or make sure all ads have a category.

Comment: Superb! Thanks. it was the issue.